# PHP MVC: Do i really need a Controller?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, controller

My question is simple but (I guess) hard to answer:

Do I really need a complete Model-View-Controller design pattern in my PHP Website / Web-App?

I can't understand how a Controller could be useful with PHP since every PHP site is generated dynamically on every request. So after a site is generated by PHP, there is no way to let the View (the generated HTML site in the Browser) interact with the controller, since the Controller is on the server side and generated once for each site request, even if the request is AJAX...

Do I understand something completely wrong?

Why should I use any kind of MVC PHP Framework like Zend or Symphony?

EDIT:
For example lets assume, there should be a website to represent a list of customers in a table:

My Model would be a simple Class Customer on the server side that queries the database.
My View would be the generated HTML code that displays the Model (list of Customers).
And the controller? Is the controller only evaluating the GET or POST to call the correct method of the model?

Comment: It's called Model View Controller (MVC). By definition that means you need a controller.

Comment: @sockeqwe , did you choose the "correct answer"  based on length. Because the current one (from Scott Bailey) is completely and utterly wrong.

Comment: @tereško , what would you change, remove or add in Scotts answer?

Comment: all of the "long answer", since it's all wrong

Comment: Do you think so? What exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Short Answer

Yes. A controller will be responsible for preparing data to display for rendering and sometimes handle GET and POST requests that originating from your client. It should leave HTML generation to the view.

## Long Answer

MVC can be very helpful in keeping applications maintainable and your code base sane. The pattern helps ensure separation of concerns of your code and in most cases will steer yor clear of 'spaghetti php' where your application logic is tangled with the HTML generation. A *sample MVC* setup below (there are sure to be many variations of this, but it gives you the idea):

#### Model

Responsible for fetching data from the database and saving changes when requested. One example might be a php  object that represents a user with name and email fields.

#### Controller

Responsible for massaging and manipulating data and preparing it for display. The prepared data is passed to a view for rendering, with the view only needing to be aware of just the data it needs to render. For example: a controller may look at a query string to determine what item to fetch to render and combine this with several additional model queries to get additional data.

Often controllers will also be responsible for handling GET and POST requests that originate from your HTML client and applying some sort of manipulation back on your database. For example - handling form submits or AJAX requests for additional data.

#### View

The view is responsible for actually generating the HTML for display. In PHP, a view would often be a template file with minimal logic. For example, it might know how to loop over items provided to it from the controller or have some basic conditionals.

**Application MVC vs PHP/Python/etc. MVC**

From your other comments it sounds like you are familiar with using MVC in the context of a desktop or mobile application.

One of the main differences between MVC in the two is the granularity at which the controller is manipulating the view and responding to events.

For example, in a traditional application the controller might listen for click events originating from a button and respond appropriately.

When your doing server side html generation however, your controller is only 'alive' for a brief moment while its preparing html to ship out over the wire. This means that it can only do so much to setup and prepare the view for display.

Instead of listening traditional events from the UI, it can instead react in different ways to future GET and POST requests. For example, you may have a "save" button on a form trigger a POST request to your server (such as yourpage.php?action=save&value=blah). While handling this request your controller might access your models and apply changes, etc.

Answer (score 5):

> Do I have understand something completely wrong?

Yes.

The MVC pattern is not for the browser. The browser sees HTML anyways. Whether this HTML is generated with C++, PHP, Java or whatever it doesn't matter. The browser doesn't care what design patterns were used to generate this HTML.

MVC is a design pattern to organize and separate responsibilities in your code. So it's not for the browser, it's for the developers writing the code. It's to create more maintainable code where you have a clear separation between your business logic (Model), the communication between the model and the view (Controller) and the UI (View).

Whether you should use the MVC pattern in your web site is a subjective question that I prefer not to answer as it will depend on many factors.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I edit my previous post (added a little example), it would be nice if you have a look at this example. I know the MVC pattern and i understand how the MVC pattern works and the advantages of it (at least in a classic desktop application), but I don't understand how to implement a controller in PHP? I mean, a site is generated with PHP on every requst, so in my opinion the HTTP itself is the controller in a Web-Application ...

Comment: I mean, in a classic java application, i would have a Controller, that listen to the View for some input (like clicking on a button), and then the Controller would let the Model do something ...

But in a Web application, I would click on a Button and something would be send to the server, and i would be redirected to a new site ( a new View) which displays something, that is depending on the button click ... But i can't see a controller in such a scenario

Comment: @sockeqwe, you are correct in that MVC for a PHP application isn't the same thing as MVC in a (for example) persistent desktop application. But that doesn't mean the controllers are useless. I think the key point in Darin's answer is that it allows you to "organize and separate responsibilities."

Comment: yeah, i completly agree with you and him, that the MVC is a pattern you should always use! But i can't see the responsibility of a Controller in PHP. Could anyone give me an example what a controller in PHP do? A sequenz diagramm (in textual form) would help =)

Comment: @Matthew Agree it is to "organize and separate responsibilities" however the responsibility which is given to the Controller with most PHP MVC applications is incorrect. The Controller is still responsible for manipulating the Model according to the users request, it is not responsible for extracting data and passing it to the View.

Comment: @sockeqwe The Controller within a PHP application is still going to be required, however you are only going to require a Controller on requests which are intended to manipulate a particular Model. You do not need a Controller to simply display some data. According to MVC principles, a View can directly access it's model.

Comment: @SandorA now 3 years later I do understand how to use MVC for web apps. The point is, that MVC for desktop application is not the same as MVC for web applications. In desktop MVC applications the controller would react on GUI events and manipulate the model. In MVC for web apps your controller is the entry point. Here you will start to handle your http request and manipulate or fetch the model and give it to the view (which represents the model as html, json). So its some kind of a middle man. To me it seems more like Model-View-Presenter Passive View if you want to compare it with desktop

Comment: @sockeqwe Yes, you are right, in that this is what has become of MVC. You are doing what is common practice and widely accepted by the majority of the community, the controller acting as a mediator/middle-man. What I am trying to add here, is the view that MVC for the web has been mutated into something which is no longer MVC. I believed that you personally would have overcome this particular issue, however, I think someone else who is where you were back then might find some use from an alternative view.

Comment: Yes, thanks for adding! From my point of view the name is just the problem (at least if you were a desktop app developer) because MVP in web apps is not the same as MVP in desktop apps, they are two differen things (like you said).

Answer (score 1):

I realise that I am answering a very old questions, however, I do not believe that any other question has answered your initial concern appropriately, and this will hopefully add something useful for others who may stumble across this question in their learning about MVC.

Firstly, I will start by saying I read an interesting article about the confusion which exists within the PHP community about MVC and it is worth a read if you are asking this type of question.

[Model-View-Confusion part 1: The View gets its own data from the Model](https://r.je/views-are-not-templates.html)

Secondly, I do not believe you have misunderstood anything at all, rather you have a better understanding of PHP and MVC which is allowing you to ask the question. Just because something has been defined and accepted by the community at large, it does not mean you should't question its use from time to time. And here is why.

There is NO memory between requests (except for SESSION state) within a PHP application. Every time a request is received the entire application fires up, processes the request and then shuts down i.e. there are no background application threads left running in the background (at least none which you can use within your application) where you could, theoretically, maintain application state. This is neither good, nor bad, it is just the way it is.

Understanding this, you can probably start to see what you are thinking is correct. Why would a View (which is allowed to access its own data from the Model) need a Controller? The simple answer, is that it doesn't. So for the pure display of a Model, the View is perfectly entitled to fetch its own data (via the Model) and it is actually the correct way to implement MVC.

But wait. Does this mean we don't need Controllers? Absolutely NOT! What we need to do is use a Controller for its appropriate purpose. In MVC, the Controller is responsible for interpreting user requests and asking the Model to change itself to meet the users request, following this, the Model can notify it's dependencies of the change and the View can update itself. Obviously, as you know, in the context of a PHP web application, the View is not just sitting and waiting for update notifications. So how can you achieve the notification?

This is where I believe MVC got hijacked. To notify the View it's Model has changed, we can simply direct them to the URL of the View which accesses the now updated Model. Great, but now we have introduced something into the Controller. Something which says, "Hey, I'm a controller but now I have knowledge of the location of the View." I think at this point, someone thought, "why do I bother redirecting the user? I have all the data which the View needs why don't I just send the data directly to the View?" and bang! Here we are.

So let's recap.

1. A View CAN access the Model directly within MVC
2. The Model houses the business logic for the Domain Objects
3. A Controller is not meant to provide the View access to the Model or act as any type of mediator
4. The Controller accepts user requests and makes changes to it's Model
5. A View is not the UI/HTML, that is where a Template is used

A practical example
To explain what I have been describing, we shall look at a simple, commonly found function within most websites today. Viewing the information of a single logged in user. We will leave many things out of our code here in order to demonstrate just the structure of the MVC approach.

Firstly lets assume we have a system where when we make a `GET` request for `/user/51` it is mapped to our `UserView` with the appropriate dependencies being injected.

Lets define our classes.

```
// UserModel.php
class UserModel {
    private $db;

    public function __construct(DB $db) {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function findById($id) {
        return $this->db->findById("user", $id);
    }
}

// UserView.php
class UserView {
    private $model;
    private $template;
    private $userId;

    public function __construct(UserModel $model, Template $template) {
        $this->model = $model;
        $this->template = $template;
    }

    public function setUserId($userId) {
        $this->userId = $userId;
    }

    public function render() {
        $this->template->provide("user", $this->model->findById($this->userId));
        return $this->template->render();
    }
}
```

And that's it! You do not require the Controller at all. If however you need to make changes to the Model, you would do so via a Controller. This is MVC.

**Disclaimer**

I do not advocate that this approach is correct and any approach taken by any developer at any point in time is wrong. I strongly believe that the architecture of any system should reflect its needs and not any one particular style or approach where necessary. All I am trying to explain is that within MVC, a View is actually allowed to directly access it's own data, and the purpose of a Controller is not to mediate between View and Model, rather it is intended to accept user requests which require manipulation of a particular Model and to request the Model to perform such operations.